# React custom hook not receiving current state of value from another custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an event handler that sets a selected value in a list to `[values, setValues]` state hook. After doing this, I have a `useEffect` hook that calls an `[options, setOptions]` state hook to set that value to the `options` value. However, although `setValues` is able to set the state (which is shown when I `console.log`, setOptions is not able to set the new `values` state to the `options` state

#### UPDATE

Moving the `console.log(options.data)` out of the effect solves the problem partially because it logs out the current value, however, returning that value and using it in another custom hook returns the default value of `options`. I have updated the code.

I have tried using useRef to get the current value but my implementation is not working. Maybe I am doing that bit wrong.

```
   const useFirstCustomHook = () => {
   const [options, setOptions] = useState({
        data: null
    })

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: "",
        myid: "my-id"
    });
    
    //state changer
    function handleChange(event, id) {
        setValues(oldValues => ({
          ...oldValues,
          name: event.target.value,
          myid: id.props.id,
        }));
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        setOptions({
            data: values
        })
        
      },[values])
      console.log(options.data) //not printing the current state
     return {
       options
     }
   }
   export default useFirstCustomHook
```

```
   const [waitState, setWait] = useState(0)
   const { values, options } = useFirstCustomHook ()
   
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log(options)
      let wait = () => {
            setTimeout(() => setWait(waitState+1), 10000)
        }

      async function fetchData() {
        //fetch some data then wait
        wait()
      }

   },[wait])
   export default useFetchedData
```

I expect the new state of `options` to be the same as the current value of `values` but it is only reflecting the default value.

Comment: `options` will not change till next render. Move `console.log` outside `useEffect`

Comment: Why did you expect that? You didn't change `options`, you used `setOptions` to ask `useState` to give you a different value next time you call it, when the component is re-rendered.

Comment: @UjinT34 it seems `options` changes when I move it out. But I can't seem to access it in another custom hook file. I think I should edit and update the question

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't really get, but `setOptions` is meant to ask `useState` to give me it's current value on next render